# How to make an interactive image plot (with bokeh?)

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to take raster (say a JPG) cut it in subregions and associate each reagion to a row in a pandas dataframe, so that the image can be visualized according to some filters on the data. I see this is pretty standard using bokeh in python, but I do not find tutorial on how to prepare the raster for this. All explanation somehow use premade data such as the counties of [texas example in bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) ...

So, what should I do to my custom image to transform it into something can be used with bokeh to make an interactive map?

Comment: Did you take a look at the texas exemple data and tried to understand how the example works?

Comment: premade? `from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties`

Comment: and just to be clear, I am looking for a tutorial, not a dive into source-code ... call me a wuss if you like : )

Comment: After calling `from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties` you could `print(counties)` to see how the dataset is structured. It is just a dictionary containing all the data needed. Then take a look at the texas example code to see how they managed to do the job. If I understand you correctly, you more or less want to do exactly what they did, just with a different dataset. And if you don't understand it, consider taking a look at the official Bokeh Tutorial and learn some basics.

Comment: Guys, I may not be asking in a way that is clear enough ... I get that I need the X,Y coordinates, I want to know `how to prepare the raster` (quoting the OP). For instance in the epoch of html `image maps` there where tools like [ImageReady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ImageReady) but they are dead since 10 years. How do I get the coordinates in a simple way (without dying in code or cut-paste) ? (I hope you see why premade data does not help here)

Comment: What is your input and what exactly is the desired output? You want to convert an image file to a "raster"? What do you mean by that? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646270/how-do-i-work-with-images-in-bokeh-python) has multiple answers, maybe it helps you.

Comment: Input JPEG file, output something I can import and plot. My current solution: 1) Ploygons can be traced in a human way in Photoshop and exported as `ImageMap` HTML with [this](https://github.com/andyhawkes/ps-paths-to-imagemap), 2) then a bit of BeautifulSoup and some Numpy massage to extract the coordinates.

Comment: You can use the Python library `cv2` to read an image file as a Numpy array. Then this array can be shown in bokeh by using the method `image_rgba(...)` of bokeh's `Figure` objects (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434555/9568847)).